# How to prevent firefox from switching to a tab thats already open when I want to open the same webpage on a different browser/tab

Tags: firefox

Not sure if this is the best place to ask this. But when I type in a web address in firefox on my second monitor, it goes straight to a tab that is already open on the same webpage on the 1st monitor, rather than creating a duplicate webpage. Its tedious having to right click all the time to duplicate a page, then drag it to my second monitor. Is there a setting I change for this?

Comment: I don’t have this behavior. But I also don’t know why I don’t have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are typing a duplicate URL, you can hold the SHIFT key while pressing Enter to open that dupe URL without switching over to the other tab that contains it.

---

A little off-topic answer

> When you enter a site in the URL/Location/Address bar and see "Switch
> to tab" in the drop-down, you can

```
use ALT+Enter to open the new (duplicate) tab anyway

use CTRL (CMD in OSX) +left-click on the original tab and drag it until you see an up arrow from below the break point between two tabs, then release the left-click key, then release the CTRL/CMD key to get a duplicate of the tab with all of its history (Back/Forward)

press the Shift key while an entry in the drop down list is highlighted to disable "Switch to Tab" and see the URL.

Use the cursor Right key to select an item marked as Switch to Tab in the drop down list and copy the URL to the location bar.

Open the URL in the current tab by using Shift + Enter on the highlighted entry.

Alt + Enter opens the highlighted URL in a new tab.

Shift + Enter opens the highlighted URL in the current tab.

Cursor Right copies the highlighted URL to the location bar in case you want to edit it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the same behavior - the typed address always replaces
the current page.

The `about:config` page has some settings that might relate to this problem.
Here are some of them and my default values, so check against yours:

- `browser.link.open_newwindow` : 3
- `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` : 2
- `browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external` : -1

If your values are identical, you may reset all preference to their
defaults by backing up the files `prefs.js` and `user.js` in your
profile folder, then delete them while Firefox is closed, and restart it.

In the worst case, export your bookmarks, uninstall Firefox,
scrub its folders and reinstall.